# CGAL: Is there a way to connect two edges from different surfaces?

Tags: computational-geometry, cgal

I am using CGAL to perform some clipping operations in my surface meshes and I wanted to re-connect different components afterwards. I wondering if there was a way to connect two border edges of open Polyhedron_3 surface meshes that lie fairly close to each other and create a composite mesh?

Here is an example:

[image: Edge connection between surfaces]

I've tried exploring the fill hole approach but I wasn't sure how to get that to work for two separate Polyhedron_3 meshes.

Answer (score 2):

If your borders are already conform you can use [`stitch_borders()`](https://cgal.geometryfactory.com/CGAL/doc/master/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__repairing__grp.html#ga8ae4352e67d2b099994ac8990c13bd41), if not you need to snap them first. You can use the undocumented function in this [header](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Polygon_mesh_processing/include/CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/internal/Snapping/snap.h) available in the master branch and upcoming 5.1 release. See also usage examples [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Polygon_mesh_processing/test/Polygon_mesh_processing/test_pmp_non_conforming_snapping.cpp).

Comment: Note that in order to call `stitch_borders()` surfaces must be in the same mesh. You can use [`copy_face_graph()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLHelperFct.html#ga2d3eb044bfe42eab566779ce32216c11) for example to import the mesh after the stitch. If the gap is a bit large, hole filling is a good idea. You can do that by using the polyline version once you identified the border edges that should be joined (as you need to add 2 extra edges to close the loop).